# Can't boot my Ubuntu 12.04 machine; displays error on start

Tags: 12.04, boot, mount, cinnamon, fsck

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 running Cinnamon desktop.  I tried to reboot, and now I get an error and the system halts.

The error is:

```
> Starting nanny (Parental Control Daemon):
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dis-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init.py:57:  GtkWarning:
> could not open display warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.warning)
> ** (twistd:2023):  Warning**: Command line'dbus-launch --autolaunch-0e42ec90e8137a7c8d6a1cc00000005 --binary-syntax --close-strerr' exited with non-zero exit status1: Autolaunch error: x11 initialization failed.\n
```

When I try to go through recovery, and remount the hard drive as read-write fsck runs and just stops.

Any ideas?

Comment: `fsck ` starting and stalling looks like a known bug in recovery.  
Go to "root shell" and type `mount / -o remount,rw`. Then exit that shell and try again.

Comment: @guntburt I would put this as an answer. May be more helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.  The problem was the hard drive was full, and XServer couldn't start.  I freed up some free space and the problem went away.